# Max Number of threads running sockets in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, virtual-machine

I want to create a Java program that accepts TCP socket connections from clients.
As soon as a client connects my server, I create a new thread to handle that client.
My doubt is that if I am running a Ubuntu VM for the server with single core Processor, how many clients can I support?
Also, is the max number of threads dependent upon the number of processors?
If you would like to suggest some optimizations on server-side code for client handling, please do so. Here's the code snippet:

```
SS = new ServerSocket(8080);
while(1) {
Socket S = SS.accept();
BufferedReader DIS = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(S.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter DOS = new PrintWriter(S.getOutputStream(),true);
ServerThread CT = new ServerThread(S,DIS,DOS); // Class to handle client functions
Thread T = new Thread(CT);
T.start(); }
```

As you can see, more the number of clients, more threads are created.

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto thanks for the reference docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My doubt is that if I am running a Ubuntu VM for the server with
>   single core Processor, how many clients can I support?

No matter how many threads you create, they will be executed if processors are available. You can optimize this by checking available processors at runtime using `Runtime` class.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

> Also, is the max number of threads dependent upon the number of
>   processors?

AFAIK, you can create threads, but they will only be in the running state when a processor is available.